# Converting Jquery to Vanilla JS - floating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagespeed

```
    //First function -> Makes a heading float when scrolled past it
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)').matches) {
    $(function(){
var topBlockheight=$('.site-header').height();
        // Check the initial Position of the fixed_nav_container
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('.float-h2').offset().top;
        var stopFloat = $('#stop-float').offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( (  $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop-topBlockheight && $(window).scrollTop() < stopFloat-topBlockheight )) {
                        $('.float-h2').css({position: 'fixed', top: '200px'});  
                }
                else {
                        $('.float-h2').css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                }
        });
  });
}

// Adds Hover effect for boxes
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)').matches) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".thumb-cta").mouseover(function(){
    max_value=4;
    random_value= Math.floor((Math.random() * max_value) + 1);
    $(this).attr("data-random",random_value);
});
})
}
```

These are my two only functions in jQuery from my site which i decided to try to rewrite in vanilla JS. The reason for this decision is because I dont want a 90kb file (jquery main file) to be loaded for 2 basic functions (basic but still can't do them, yes I know).

I've tryed to re write them using http://youmightnotneedjquery.com and https://www.workversatile.com/jquery-to-javascript-converter and i ended up with this code, which does not have any errors in the console, but still does not work :((

```
            let el = document.getElementById("masthead");
            let topBlockheight = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el, null).height.replace("px", ""))

            var rect = document.getElementById("float-h2").getBoundingClientRect();

            var offset = { 
                            top: rect.top + window.scrollY, 
                            left: rect.left + window.scrollX, 
                        };


                        var brect = document.getElementById("stop-float").getBoundingClientRect();

            var boffset = { 
                            top: rect.top + window.scrollY, 
                            left: rect.left + window.scrollX, 
                        };

                    window.scroll(function(){
                            if( (  window.scrollTop() > rect-topBlockheight && window.scrollTop() < stopFloat-topBlockheight )) {
                                    document.getElementById("float-h2").css({position: 'fixed', top: '200px'});  
                            }
                            else {
                                    document.getElementById("float-h2").css({position: 'relative', top: '0px'});
                            }
                    });
```

Any ideas how I can move on, because I'm really stuck

Comment: Can you please update your snippets to [Minimal, Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using [Stack Snippers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) this way it's easier to debug and create a working example for you.

Comment: Did you check this? http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Please do not refer us to external sites (which might change at any point in the future) to get the proper context. A [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question.

Comment: `$('.float-h2')` vs `document.getElementById("float-h2")` is a very obvious first mismatch. Whether you made changes in the HTML as well to reflect that, we can’t currently tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- hope this work for you

```
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)').matches) {
      //Note: if "site-header" is more than one element remove [0] and create a loop
         var topBlockheight=document.getElementsByClassName('site-header')[0].offsetHeight
        var stickyHeaderTop = document.getElementsByClassName('float-h2')[0].offsetTop;
        var stopFloat = document.getElementById('stop-float').offsetTop;
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
                if( (  window.scrollY > stickyHeaderTop-topBlockheight && window.scrollY < stopFloat-topBlockheight )) {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('float-h2')[0].style.position = 'fixed'
                  document.getElementsByClassName('float-h2')[0].style.top = '200px'
                }
                else {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('float-h2')[0].style.position = 'relative'
                  document.getElementsByClassName('float-h2')[0].style.top = 0
                }
        });
}

// Adds Hover effect for boxes
if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 767px)').matches) {
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(document.readyState === "interactive") {
     document.getElementsByClassName('thumb-cta')[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    max_value=4;
    random_value= Math.floor((Math.random() * max_value) + 1);
      this.setAttribute("data-random",random_value);
    });
  }
 }
}
```

## Details

1. **jQuery**

- in jQuery to select elements by className or tagName it's enough to write `$('.element')` or `$('tag')` but in Vanillajs to select  elements you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('elements')` or `document.getElementsByTagName('elements')` which return found elements sharing the same className or tagName in an array if you want to select only one element you can write the element index like `document.getElementsByClassName('elements')[0]` but if you want to select all elements you will be need to create a loop

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('elements')
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].style.padding = '25px';
  el[i].style.background = 'red';
}
```

and because of id is unque name for the element you don't need to any extra steps you can select it diectly select it like `document.getElementById('id')`

that was about selecting elements

- `height()` method which uses get the element height - in Vanillajs js to get the element height you can use `offsetHeight` property or `getComputedStyle(element, pseudo|null).cssProp`

**Example**
`element.offsetHeight`, `parseInt(getComputedStyle(element, null).height)`

- `offset()` method which uses to return coordinates of the element this method have 2 properties `top`, `left` in Vanillajs to get the element offset top you can use `offsetTop` propery directly like `element.offsetTop`
- jQuery provides a prototype method like `css()` which provide an easy and readable way to styling elements like in normal object `propery: value` - in Vanillajs to styling elements you will be need to use `style` object like `element.style.prop = 'value'`  and you will be need to repeat this line every time you add new css property like

```
el.style.padding = '25px';
el.style.background = 'red';
//and they will repeated as long as you add new property
```

if you don't want to include jQuery into your project and need to use this method you can define it as prototype method for `HTMLElement`, `HTMLMediaElement`

> Example 1: for styling one element

```
//for html elements
HTMLElement.prototype.css = function(obj) {
  for(i in obj) {
    this.style[i] = obj[i]
  }
}
//for media elements like video, audio
HTMLMediaElement.prototype.css = function(obj) {
  for(i in obj) {
    this.style[i] = obj[i]
  }
}
//Usage
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('elements')[0]
el.css({
  'padding': '25px',
  'background-color': 
})
```

if you wants to add this style for multiple elements you can define it as prototype method for `Array`

> Example 2: for multiple elements

```
Array.prototype.css = function(obj) {
  for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] instanceof HTMLElement) {
      for(r in obj) {
        this[i].style[r] = obj[r]
      }
    }
  }
}
//Usage
var el1 = document.getElementsByClassName('elements')[0]
var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName('elements')[1]
[el1, el2].css({
  'background-color': 'red',
  padding: '25px'
})
```

- jQuery allow you to add events directly when selecting element like `$('.element').click(callback)` but in Vanillajs you can add events with `addEventListener()` or `onevent` proprty like `document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click', callback)` , `document.getElementById('id').onclick = callback`
- `$(document).ready(callback)` this method uses to make your code start working after loading the libraries, other things it's useful to give the lib enough time to loaded to avoid errors - in Vanilla js you can use `onreadystatechange` event and `document.readyState` protpety which have 3 values `loading`, `interactive`, `complete`

> Example

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
    //your code here
  }
}
```

2. **Your Coverted Code**

- at this line `parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el, null).height.replace("px", ""))` you don't need to replace any thing because `parseInt()`, `parseFloat` will ignore it
- `element.css()` id don't know how you don't get any errors in the console when this method is undefined you will be need to define it as above to make it work
- `scroll` event is not defined you will be need to use `window.onscroll = callback` like example above

Comment: Always provide an explanation of what was changed and why. Code only answers are not very valuable long term and users shouldn't be expected to go line by line looking for differences

Comment: That was godlike!! Thank you very much!

Unfortunately, only the first box with class name "thumb-cta" has the hover effect with the changing colors.

Also can you go into detail (if its not too much to ask) on what i did wrong?

Comment: i edited it and added the details i wasn't want to include it because this is too much